# Symfony Flex configuration for KnpLabs/DoctrineBehaviors

Tags: symfony, doctrine, symfony4, symfony-flex

I would like to configure `knp_doctrine_behaviors` for `knplabs/doctrine-behaviors` like this:

```
knp_doctrine_behaviors:
    translatable:   true
```

but Symfony (flex) give me error:

*[FileLoaderLoadException] There is no extension able to load the configuration for "knp_doctrine_behaviors" ... Looked for namespace "knp_doctrine_behaviors", found ...*

Im new to Symfony Flex so I dont fully understand what should I do

symfony.lock:

```
"knplabs/doctrine-behaviors": {
    "version": "1.5.0"
},
```

Comment: Are you using Symfony 4? did you load the bundle in `config/bundles.php`?

Comment: @Orange18947 yes symfony 4 ... and u r right, thats the problem, I thought that bundles are registered automatically because I removed AppKernel and didnt know `bundles.php` exists ... so just recipes are added automatically there if I understand, THX

Comment: Yep.  Only recipes automatically update the config stuff (bundles.php, routing, general config files).  Lack of a recipe should actually raise a bit of a flag.  Many third party bundles do not support S4.  So be cautious.

Comment: In latest version the config key is without prefix `doctrine_behaviors:`

Answer (score 2):

You have to add

```
    Knp\DoctrineBehaviors\Bundle\DoctrineBehaviorsBundle::class => ['all' => true],
```

to your bundles.php